# How to connect a destroyed signal of C++ object from QML?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qtquick2

I want to connect a destroyed signal of C++ `QObject` from QML so I did this:

```
Rectangle
{
    id: root
    width: 128
    height: 128

Button
{
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    text: "Click me"
    onClicked:
    {
        qobj.Component.onDestruction.connect(function(){console.log("It destroy")}) // qobj is set from c++
        qobj.destroy() // should output "It destroy"
    }
}
```

But nothing is printed when I destroy `qobj`.

Comment: What's `function(){...}`?

Comment: `function(){console.log("It destroyed!")}`  an anonymous function that put a word to console,isn't it?

Comment: Oh, why is this tagged C++ then?

Comment: yea, it's my bad and i fixed the question. sorry...

Comment: [connect](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-signals.html#connecting-signals-to-methods-and-signals) should be used with the SIGNAL, not with the HANDLER, i.e. you should use `destruction.connect` (see link above). Apart from that, is `qobj` a context property?

Comment: Yes, qobj is a context property. And  `qobj.destruction`  or   `qobj.destroyed`  is `undefined`.

Comment: AFAIK using `.connect` with the handler works now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the general case, you can connect to signals emitted from a C++ object using a [Connections](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-connections.html) element:

```
Connections {
    target: yourObjectComingFromCpp
    onSomeSignal: console.log("Something")
}
```

or in Javascript by calling the `connect` function on the corresponding property of the JS-mapped object:

```
// without the *on*!
yourObjectComingFromCpp.someSignal.connect( /* JS function here */ );
```

---

**However**: this doesn't work for the specific `QObject::destroyed` signals, which are forcibly blacklisted and never available in QML ([source](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/qml/qml/qqmlpropertycache.cpp.html#626)).

I guess the reason is that the object is gone from the QML context anyhow at that point, plus when that signal is emitted you're deep into QObject's own destructor, which means any property or method access on your subclass is invalid at that point.

Comment: `qobj` is a context property and i want to connect its signals from javascript only. i've tried `qobj.onDestroyed.connect(...)` and failed.(`TypeError: Cannot call method 'connect' of undefined`)

Comment: What do you mean with "is a context property"? Are you exposing `qobj` using `setContextProperty`? And: the right syntax would be: `qobj.destroyed.connect(...)` (not *on*).

Comment: `qobj.destroyed` is also `undefined`.

Comment: @peppe told you that such signal is blacklisted. That's it, period. The `on..` syntax cannot be used, it's wrong, as specified by both me and @peppe.

Comment: Well. I added a custom signal for destruction. Thanks for everyone.